# Is this girl really from Bleach?

Tags: bleach

On some sites which have ads I've been seeing the following image

possibly NSFW if you look hard enough

> [image: Bleach Girl]

Now I've only seen up to episode 130 and I've never seen her before. However she kind of looks like Lighting (AKA Clare Farron) from Final Fantasy XIII.

I am wondering: is this girl really from Bleach? If so when would I see her in the series (which episode or chapter), and if not where is she from?

Comment: If she *is* from bleach she's very badly drawn. I don't recognize her.

Comment: It looks like it could be a really weirdly stylized version of Matsumoto. Other than that, I think it's just a made up character. EDIT: When searching through TheAnimeGallery, it shows it as a Final Fantasy XIII character.

Comment: she's lightning from FF XIII with 'bigger' size

Comment: You might want to censor this because it's NSFW. You can see a certain thing behind the clothes...

Comment: @MaxLi didn't really notice that. I would stick this in a spoiler block but at the moment I am on an iPad and >! does seem to want to work (it instead shows a regular quote). it's still a few hours before I go onto my PC but if this hasn't been edited by then I'll get it fixed

Comment: dafuq Eclaire "Lightning" Farron doin in Bleach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This isn't a Bleach character. This is, as you guessed, Lightning from Final Fantasy XIII, at least according to [this page](http://www.theanimegallery.com/gallery/image:119539/final-fantasy-xiii:lightning-anime-version) on TheAnimeGallery.

Comment: +1 and Accepted now because you located a source of the image proving that she isn't from Bleach

Comment: The image seems to be from a doujinshi of FF13 by "carrot works", at least according to (**NSFW!**) `https://danbooru.donmai.us/posts/448925`